# Changing the order of switch toggle and label in bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

How to change the order of the switch and the label in bootstrap 5. The order in the code doesn't make a difference.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Switch first then label</label>
</div>


<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Label first then switch</label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

See the snippet below.

```css
.form-check {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.form-check-input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.form-check-label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Switch first then label</label>
</div>


<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Label first then switch</label>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
</div>
```